# Did NME really say Public Image Limited was "arguably the first post-rock group"?

Tags: history, rock

On the Wikipedia page for Post Rock ([Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-rock)) it says that the magazine New Musical Express has stated that Public Image Limited was "arguably the first post-rock group" (the quotation is from the article, suggesting that's *exactly* what was said). However, the citation for the quote is incorrect - those words, or even their sentiment, are not in the linked article.

I would like to correct the citation, but whenever I search for those words, I just get links back to Wikipedia, rather than the original source. So now I'm not even sure if NME *ever* said such a thing.

Anyone have any thoughts on correcting this citation?

Comment: It's Wikipedia --if the info is not supported by the citation, just remove it.  Adding an inaccurate citation is an easy way to "launder" fake information, because few people actually follow up.

Comment: oh I know, and I will be removing it, I would rather just replace it with a correction rather than nothing.

Comment: It's the kind of thing the NME would say, which is probably why the statement persists...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wiki page contains citation #25,  "NME Reviews: Plastic Box". NME. January 11, 1999. Archived from the original on June 10, 2008. Retrieved July 8, 2008."

The archived URL at https://web.archive.org/web/20080610054006/http://www.nme.com/reviews/public-image-ltd/641 contains the full quotation:

"Arguably the first post-rock group, they traded traditional rock influences for something far more interesting."

Click on the first link within the reference labelled. "NME Reviews: Plastic Box."

The second link labelled "the original" just takes you to the main NME website.  I did a search for PiL and the quotation but couldn't locate it, suggesting that it is only available from the archive.